# Getting values from form input groups

Tags: forms, reactjs, material-ui

I have a group of form inputs that are produced like so:

Please see UPDATE 2 below for full component.

So, if there are three columns then three of this group will be shown in the form. I am trying to extract the data from these inputs but I only need the ids. How can I extract the column id from the `TextField`?

Also, I need to get the data (i.e. the ids) per group so that they appear in an array:

```
transformations: [{columnId: 1, ruleId: 4}, {columnId: 2, ruleId: 2}, {columnId:3 , ruleId: 1}]
```

These are just example values, the main problem as I mentioned, is that I'm not sure how to extract the value of the `columnId` from the first input. I'm also struggling with getting the multiple sets of data.

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

UPDATE:

handleRuleChange looks like this:

```
handleRuleChange = (e, index, value) => {
  this.setState({
    ruleId: value
  })
}
```

UPDATE 2:

Here is the component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Relay from 'react-relay'

import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField'
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem'
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField'

import CreateTransformationSetMutation from '../mutations/CreateTransformationSetMutation'

class CreateTransformationSetDialog extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.setOnDialog({
      onSubmit: this.onSubmit,
      title: 'Create and Apply Transformation Set'
    })
  }

  initial_state = {
    targetTableName: '',
    ruleId: 'UnVsZTo1',
  }

  state = this.initial_state

  onSubmit = () => {
    const onSuccess = (response) => {
      console.log(response)
      browserHistory.push('/table')
    }

    const onFailure = () => {}

    Relay.Store.commitUpdate(
      new CreateTransformationSetMutation(
        {
          viewer: this.props.viewer,
          version: this.props.viewer.version,
          targetTableName: this.state.targetTableName,
          transformations: ///this is where I need to get the values///,
        }
      ),
      { onSuccess: onSuccess }
    )
  }

  handleTextChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      targetTableName: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleRuleChange = (e, index, value) => {
    this.setState({
      ruleId: value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          floatingLabelText="Table Name"
          value={this.state.targetTableName}
          onChange={this.handleTextChange} 
        />
        <br />
        {
          this.props.viewer.version.columns.edges.map((edge) => edge.node).map((column) =>
            <div key={column.id}>
              <TextField
                id={column.id}
                floatingLabelText="Column"
                value={column.name}
                disabled={true}
                style={{ margin: 12 }} 
              />
              <SelectField
                floatingLabelText="Select a Rule"
                value={this.state.ruleId}
                onChange={this.handleRuleChange}
                style={{ margin: 12 }}
              >
                {
                  this.props.viewer.allRules.edges.map(edge => edge.node).map(rule =>
                    <MenuItem
                      key={rule.id}
                      value={rule.id}
                      primaryText={rule.name}
                    />
                  )
                }
              </SelectField>
            </div>
          )
        }

      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Relay.createContainer(CreateTransformationSetDialog, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        ${CreateTransformationSetMutation.getFragment('viewer')}
        version(id: $modalEntityId) @include(if: $modalShow) {
          ${CreateTransformationSetMutation.getFragment('version')}
          id
          name
          columns(first: 100) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
        allRules(first: 100) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  },
  initialVariables: {
    modalEntityId: '',
    modalName: '',
    modalShow: true,
  },
  prepareVariables: ({ modalEntityId, modalName }) => {
    return {
      modalEntityId,
      modalName,
      modalShow: modalName === 'createTransformationSet'
    }
  }
})
```

It is using `Relay` but that isn't connected to the question, just need to extract the data from the inputs into the transformations array.

Comment: can you show your `handleRuleChange` method?

Comment: Would be awesome if you didn't delete your previous questions ;-)

Comment: And your `initial state` ? Better to add complete component here. Not sure what you are doing there?

Comment: Sorry that was my bad! Had a bit of a rewrite of the code so that question wasn't really relevant for me anymore. But I agree with you it was poor form of me to delete it!

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can meet your requirement. Most of code will be understandable. feel free to ask for queries.

```
class CreateTransformationSetDialog extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.setOnDialog({
      onSubmit: this.onSubmit,
      title: 'Create and Apply Transformation Set'
    })
  }

  initial_state = {
    targetTableName: '',
    transformations: [];
    ruleId:'UnVsZTo1' //default values for all rules
  }

  state = this.initial_state

  onSubmit = () => {
    const onSuccess = (response) => {
      console.log(response)
      browserHistory.push('/table')
    }

    const onFailure = () => {}

    Relay.Store.commitUpdate(
      new CreateTransformationSetMutation(
        {
          viewer: this.props.viewer,
          version: this.props.viewer.version,
          targetTableName: this.state.targetTableName,
          transformations: this.state.transformations,
        }
      ),
      { onSuccess: onSuccess }
    )
  }

  handleTextChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      targetTableName: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleRuleChange = (index, ruleId, columnId) => { //TODO: make use of index if needed
    let transformations = this.state.transformations;
    const isInStateWithIndex = transformations.findIndex((el) => el.columnId === columnId);
    if(isInStateWithIndex > -1){
      transformations[isInStateWithIndex].ruleId = ruleId; //changed rule
    }else{
      transformations.push({columnId: columnId, ruleId: ruleId}); //new column added to state.
    }
    this.setState({
      transformations: transformations
    }); //do with es6 spread operators to avoid immutability if any
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          floatingLabelText="Table Name"
          value={this.state.targetTableName}
          onChange={this.handleTextChange} 
        />
        <br />
        {
          this.props.viewer.version.columns.edges.map((edge) => edge.node).map((column) =>
            <div key={column.id}>
              <TextField
                id={column.id}
                floatingLabelText="Column"
                value={column.name}
                disabled={true}
                style={{ margin: 12 }} 
              />
              <SelectField
                floatingLabelText="Select a Rule"
                value={this.state.ruleId}
                onChange={(e, index, value) => this.handleRuleChange(index, value, column.id )}
                style={{ margin: 12 }}
              >
                {
                  this.props.viewer.allRules.edges.map(edge => edge.node).map(rule =>
                    <MenuItem
                      key={rule.id}
                      value={rule.id}
                      primaryText={rule.name}
                    />
                  )
                }
              </SelectField>
            </div>
          )
        }

      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Maintaining the state for `transformations` in state with dynamically created `columns`.

Comment: This gives me an error when I try to change the select field value for any column after the first one: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. Also the reason I had the state of the ruleId set is because that is the default rule id that should be associated with the column if it isn't changed so that also needs to be in there.

Comment: There is also something funky going on with the index values, as when I click on the second dropdown it gives me an index of 2 when it should be 1.

Comment: Oh sorry I'll take a look at it now

Comment: Yeah that works! Thanks! Just one more question. I need the ruleId to be populated with that id that was in my original initial state so the starting array actually should be `[{ruleId: 'UnVsZTo1'}, {ruleId: 'UnVsZTo1'}, {ruleId: 'UnVsZTo1'}]` and then the columnId needs to be pushed into each of those objects, and of course the ruleId can be changed. Could you give me your thoughts on how to do this? Sorry about that only just realised that I needed the default rule to be in there!

Comment: My bad I described it poorly transformations should already be populated with `[{columnId: 1, ruleId: 'UnVsZTo1'}, {columnId: 2, ruleId: 'UnVsZTo1'}, {columnId: 3, ruleId: 'UnVsZTo1'}]` when it is initialised. The rule id then needs to be updated when the selection in the dropdown is changed. I have the ruleId separate as well because I need to update what is selected in the dropdown so that needs to be updated separately. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: In that case initialise the state with full array of objects as stated. Then use index to address the value for each dropdown. `this.state.ruleId` changes to `this.state.transformations[index].ruleId;